# How can I define a percentage from another percentage between a specific interval

Tags: rotations, angle

I have a cube that rotates. When the rotation is at 45 degrees I need to scale the cube to 90% of its size.

My struggle here is to calculate the amount of percentage to scale the cube according to the rotation angle. Until it is half way the scale continuously decreases to 90%, after half way rotation it needs to start increasing to 100%.

How can I calculate this?

Comment: Are you asking for a function which linearly changes from 1 to 0.9 in the interval 0 to 45 degrees and then linearly changes from 0.9 to 1 in the interval 45 to 90 degrees?

Comment: Sort of. To be clearer, I have a cube with 4 faces, front, right, back and left. I need to rotate the cube left or right. It is considered a "full rotation" every 90 degree rotation.

I can increase the angles constantly so it can be more than 360 degrees rotations increasing by 1 unit (ex: 361,362, 363 degrees, etc) but the degrees can't be lower than zero. 

Every time a rotation starts, until it reaches half rotation, the value 1 should continuously decrease until it reaches 0.9 at half rotation. From half rotation to a full 90 degree rotation, the value should increase from 0.9 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the job $$S(x) = 0.9 + \frac{\lvert 45 - x  \pmod {90}\rvert}{450}$$
where $S(x)$ is the scaling factor and $x$ is the angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question though where does the 450 come from?

Comment: You're welcome. The maximum of the function occurs when x (mod 90) is 0. At this point, the value of the function must be 1. Hence the 450. If you would like to reciprocate, click the check mark.